# Lout Manager for re-sizing of panels

Tags: java, user-interface, layout, panel, frame

I am making a gui application where I need a wide panel on one side of the frame, and a thinner panel on the other. The panels are the same height, but when I re-size them I want them to keep a consistent width difference from each other while still changing size.

Here is what it would look like when restored to a smaller size:
[image: Smaller]

And here is what it would look like when it was maximized or made bigger:
[image]

I was trying to use Grid Layout for this, but I couldn't quite figure out how to make one smaller and change at a lesser rate when you were making the window bigger. My question is which layout would get me to what I want, and what functions within the layout manager would lead me to the result?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `GridBagLayout`, but that always seems more trouble than its worth.

Instead, take a look at [JGoodies](http://www.jgoodies.com/), especially their [FormLayout](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/libraries/forms/). It's been years since I've done Swing programming, but remember the JGoodies layouts making life a lot easier.